# Validando form com onsubmit e javascript

Tags: javascript

estou tendo um probleminha na validação de um formulario 
estou utilizando ajax para validar os campos

Problema 
o onsubmit espera um retorno tipo booleano e não estou conseguindo fazer esse retorno

coloquei um contador dentro do .done(function (html)) mas esse contador só funciona dentro do mesmo quando eu tento recuperar o valor do contador fora do .done(function (html) ele está zerado
segue meu codígo

```
function validaFormALterar(acao) {
    var opc = acao;
    var erro = 0;

    var url = 'model/validarSenha.php';
    var Csenha = 'Csenha=' + $('#Csenha').val();

    var dados = Csenha;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: dados,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        if (html == 'erro') {
            //não consigo pegar o valor desse ERRO fora do DONE
            erro++;
        }
    });

    //erro sempre chegando 0
    console.log("Erro nº " + erro);

    if(erro==0){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Defina uma variável externa ao `ajax`, porém dentro da função e atribua o valor a ela.

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa realizar a validação através de uma requisição AJAX, então defina uma função de callback como parâmetro no método `validaFormALterar`.

```
function validaFormAlterar(acao, callback) {
  var opc = acao;
  var isValid = true;

  var url = 'model/validarSenha.php';

  var Csenha = 'Csenha=' + $('#Csenha').val();
  var dados = Csenha;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: dados,
    cache: false
  }).done(function (html) {
    if (html == 'erro') {
      isValid = false;
    }
    callback(isValid);
  });
}
```

A chamada ao método ao validaFormAlterar será feito da seguinte forma, passando uma função que recebe como parâmetro se a validação foi bem sucedida ou não, esta será a nossa função de callback;

Você deverá continuar com o processamento da pagina no corpo desta função

```
validaFormAlterar("minha ação", function (isValid) {
  if (isValid) {
    //valido com sucesso
  } else {
    //ocorreu erros de validação.
  }
});
```

Você até pode transformar a função AJAX em síncrona como sugerido [Yure Pereira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/33799/yure-pereira), mas não aconselho que faça isto, pois esterá mantando a principal vantagem de se utilizar uma requisição AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Faz uma requisição ajax não assíncrona, pois quando assíncrona o fluxo do código continua sendo interpretado mesmo que a requisição ainda não tenha retornado a resposta do servidor, assim fazendo com que a função do **done** seja executada depois do bloco de código que está fora dele, onde você não consergue pegar o **erro++**.

```
function validaFormALterar(acao) {
  var opc = acao;
  var erro = 0;

  var url = 'model/validarSenha.php';

  var Csenha = 'Csenha=' + $('#Csenha').val();
  var dados = Csenha;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: dados,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
  }).done(function (html) {
    if (html == 'erro') {
      //não consigo pegar o valor desse ERRO fora do DONE
      erro++;
    }
  })
  //erro sempre chegando 0
  console.log("Erro nº " + erro);
  if(erro==0){
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: requisição Ajax não assíncrona é totalmente não recomendado.

Comment: Sim, mas não pode generalizar, cada caso é um caso, como nesse caso o fato da requisição ser assíncrona faz com que o erro dele ocorra.

Comment: Mas também não querendo dizer que não tenha outras soluções que resolva isso.